# Monty Hall Gone Crazy

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, combinatorics, permutation-test

Can Someone help me out with these ?Answer along with solution will be much appreciated

Q1) Imagine that now host have the following instructions. Put a prize behind a random door. Let the guest guess a door.

1. If the guest chooses an incorrect door (with no prize), roll a dice (in such a way that the guest does not see this and does not know whether this happened);

a) with probability 1/3 (outcomes 1 and 2) open the door (that has no prize behind); the game ends;

b) with probability 2/3 (outcomes 3,4,5,6) open the other door with no prize and ask the guest whether she wants to change the guess.

2. if the guest chooses a correct door (with a prize), open one of the two other doors (making a random choice) and ask the guest whether she wants to change the guess.

What is the probability for the guest to get a prize if she uses "change" strategy (i.e., changes the guess)? We consider the fraction of winning days among all days (when she was given a chance to change or when she was not).

Q 2)The same scenario is used (as in the previous exercise). Put a prize behind a random door. Let the guest guess a door.

1. If the guest chooses an incorrect door (with no prize), roll a dice (in such a way that the guest does not see this and does not know whether this happened);

a) with probability 1/3 (outcomes 1 and 2) open the door (that has no prize behind); the game ends;

b) with probability 2/3 (outcomes 3,4,5,6) open the other door with no prize and ask the guest whether she wants to change the guess.

2. if the guest chooses a correct door (with a prize), open one of the two other doors (making a random choice) and ask the guest whether she wants to change the guess.

What is the probability for the guest to get a prize if she uses "keep" strategy (i.e., does not change the guess)? We consider the fraction of winning days among all day (when she was given a chance to change or when she was not).

Comment: Welcome to the site! If this is coursework, it should have the "self-study" tag.